# How to refresh layout in EXTJS

Tags: extjs

Beginner with extjs here so please feel free to correct me if my understanding of how extjs works is incorrect...

How do you refresh a layout after re-creating a project combo? I have a project combo whose values must change depending on the state on boolean data received from the back-end. The front-end performs a check on this data after the initComponent function has been called, in function A, after the project combo for the modal has already been set to a default value in the initComponent function.

In A, I want to call the create project combo function again this time passing it a boolean dependdent on the data obtained in the back-end. The only problem with this is that I can't seem to be able to "refresh" the layout after setting the new project combo box (so the first combo box is still what appears in the browser).

Comment: Just describe the problem, the small snippet you've posted doesn't make sense. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Next step, post the relevant code, you only posted a tiny snippet without any context.

Comment: @akperkins1 can you give your skype name? or else add me (vinojash)

Comment: @vino20 Ok, I will add you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you recreate the combobox ? Couldn't you just reload the store with the new paramater

```
var store = myCombo.getStore();
store.baseParams.myParamName = myValue;
store.reload();
```

If you still want to recreate the combobox, you should call doLayout() method of your combo's parent container.

Comment: This was , for the most part, correct. The only issue was that instead of reload(), I used load() and reset() on the store as well.